# Dymola Results of checkModel()

Tags: dymola

`checkmodel([Some Model])` opens the GUI "Dymola Messages", tab "Translation" and displays `Errors`, `Warnings`, and `Messages`.

Does anyone know how to write these infos to a logfile or get them as kind of return value of `checkModel()`. All I've found in the documentation was, that `checkModel()` only returns a success-boolean. Are these infos saved temporarily somewhere?

Note, that I only want to apply `checkModel()` but not actually translating the code.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution at least for Dymola 2016 and newer, so if someone is interested - here it is (it is not very user-friendly, but it works):

The key-command is `getLastError()` which not only returns the last error (as one could think...), but all errors that are detected by `checkModel()` as well as the overall statistics.

All informations are sampled in one string, in which the last lines looks like:

```
"[...]
Local classes checked, checking <[Some Path]>
ERROR: 2 errors were found
WARNING: 13 warnings were issued
= false
"
```

Following operations will return the number of actual errors (for warnings it is more or less the same):

```
b = checkmodel([Some Model])
s = getLastError()
ind1 = Modelica.Utilities.Strings.findLast(s,"ERROR:")
ind2 = Modelica.Utilities.Strings.findLast(s," errors were found")
nErrors = Modelica.Utilities.Strings.substring(s,ind1+6,ind2) //6 = len(ERROR:)
nErrors = Modelica.Utilities.Strings.replace(nErrors," ","")
nErrors
  = "2"
```

Note:

1. I used `findLast` as I know, that the lines of interest are at the very end of the string. So this is significantly faster than using `find`
2. This only works, if the line "ERROR: ...." actually exists. Otherwise, the `substring` call will throw an error.
3. Of course this could be done in less lines, but maybe this version is easier to read.

NOTE: This will only works with Dymola 2016 and newer. The return-string of `getLastError` is of a different structure in Dymola 2015 and older.

Answer (score 1):

The following should handle it:
    clearlog(); // To start fresh
    Advanced.TranslationInCommandLog=true;
    checkModel(...);
    savelog(...);

This is mentioned in the Dymola User Manual Volume 1, section "Parameter studies by running Dymola a number of time in “batch mode”" on pg 630 or so.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - didn't know about this parameter. Actually, these commands makes it easier to access the information from other tools, while the use of lasterror() gives the possibility to hande the data within Dymola without writing/reading external files.  But nevertheless, this works too